# Change font size of labels in matplot3D

Tags: matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I have code like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='r', marker='o',label='A')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='b', marker='^',label='B')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=6)

plt.savefig(outfile)
```

The `tickparams` which works in the 2D version is not working.

How do I do this? The documentation is very hard to read on this.

Note, this is the font size of the titles of the axes, not the tick labels.

Comment: Since you mention font size in the title of your question: that's working perfectly fine for me using exactly your example with `ax.tick_params`. The other parameters (minor/major) indeed don't seem to work

Comment: Using label size doesn't change the parameters in a 3d plot.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand you correctly, but on my system (Linux,  matplotlib 1.5.1, both with Python 3.5.1 and 2.7.11) changing `labelsize` does change the font size of the tick labels.

Comment: Do you have a 3d chart?

Comment: Yes, with your exact example, using `projection='3d'`

Comment: Hmm very strange. Let me test again, but it wasn't working before.

Comment: This is the code that I used: http://pastebin.com/HhEyaaDs, with this figure as the result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rY81s.png

Comment: Ah OK now I know. I have to change th e font size of the titles of the axes, not the ticks

Comment: Can you try the 2.0.0b3 pre release?  This _may_ have been fixed

Comment: What would be the code I am trying?

Answer (score 0):

The code from the question runs fine.

```
ax.tick_params(..., labelsize=6)
```

can be used to change the fontsize of the labels.

The complete example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x,y,z = zip(*np.random.rand(10,3))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='b', marker='^',label='B')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=6)

plt.show()
```

produces this plot:

[image]